# FTP progress bar uploading file

Tags: java, android, ftp, progress-bar

Hi guys I am using apache.commons.net to upload my files from sd card to a ftp server created by file zilla. However, all I want to do is to show the progress to the users. Could you please help me?
here is my code:

http://pastie.org/4433482

Comment: Please provide more information, paste your code here etc.

Comment: yes sure. the only info that I can provide is my bar starts from 0 in 3 seconds it goes up to 100 but in between there is nothing shown to the user I will post my code.

Comment: really I think you should be using handlers for this. Your code that is talking http, json, should be on another thread and away from the main GUI thread

Comment: @t0mm13b I did not get you exactly.

Comment: One thing for you to check - can you confirm by modifying the lines 324, and adding the `@Override` annotation on top of the method, and put in a `Log.d` method call to see if the logcat does indeed get spammed? *have you actually thought of it?*

Comment: @t0mm13b where and what should I insert Log.d?

Answer (score 2):

if in case you never solve your problem yet. I think the problem is within this line
publishProgress

`((int) ((totalBytesTransferred/file.length())*100))`

instead try this

```
publishProgress((int) ((totalBytesTransferred * 100)/file.length()))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with this line:

```
publishProgress((int) ((totalBytesTransferred/file.length())*100));
```

Since totalBytesTransferred is long and File.length() returns long, and integer division will be performed. So this line will return zero until totalBytesTransferred equals file.length(). It will then return 100.

You could cast totalBytesTransferred to double before dividing like this to get the percentage:

```
publishProgress((int) (((double)totalBytesTransferred/file.length())*100));
```

Comment: Yes both are long (sorry, I misread), but my point still holds - It will be an integer division. You could for example cast to double before dividing. I'll edit the answer...

Comment: but publishProgress method should have an int value to perform bro

Comment: lets keep it an integer-division and change the order:
publishProgress((int) ((totalBytesTransferred*100)/file.length()));

Comment: the problem ekholm stated is:
50/100 f.e. results in 0.5 since this is an integer-division, it will be converted into an integer and rounded to 0. 0 * 100 stays 0

Comment: @Kostronor nothing is changed sorry.

Comment: @Kostronor: You're right about that, it should be enough changing the order

Comment: I changed it but the result is the same starts from 0 to 100 just 2 number in the bar.

Comment: @answer88: Did you confirm while debugging that publishProgress gets called with the expected values?

Comment: can you add System.out.println(totalBytesTransferred + " | " + file.length() + " | " + ((totalBytesTransferred*100)/file.length())); before every publishProgress and give us the output?

Comment: @Kostronor I tried what you say but I can not able to see the results I am new on android how can I see the results?

Comment: you can see the in logcat, this is your android-console. what ide are you using?

Comment: @Kostronor I am using Eclipse

Comment: then simply open your logcat-view and you can see output

Comment: here is 
 D/dalvikvm(983): GC_CONCURRENT freed 538K, 54% free 3137K/6727K, external 2011K/2137K, paused 6ms+11ms
 W/KeyCharacterMap(983): No keyboard for id 0
08-09 13:35:33.760: W/KeyCharacterMap(983): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
08-09 13:36:58.480: I/dalvikvm(983): Jit: resizing JitTable from 1024 to 2048
 W/KeyCharacterMap(983): No keyboard for id 0
W/KeyCharacterMap(983): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
 D/dalvikvm(983): GC_CONCURRENT freed 947K, 57% free 2940K/6727K, external 2011K/2137K, paused 4ms+3ms

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15126/discussion-between-answer88-and-kostronor)

Comment: Still I can not find the answer but we just see that  the part where I update the progressbar is nerver reached

Comment: see my comment above your question

Answer (score 0):

On line 322 of your paste.

```
org.apache.commons.net.io.Util.copyStream(stO, stD, ftpClient.getBufferSize(),
      CopyStreamEvent.UNKNOWN_STREAM_SIZE,
      new CopyStreamAdapter() {
          public void bytesTransferred(
                   long totalBytesTransferred,
                   int bytesTransferred,
                   long streamSize) {
                      // Your progress Control code here
                      Log.d("CopyStreamAdapter", "bytesTransferred(...) - " +
                            totalBytesTransferred + "; " +
                            bytesTransferred + "; " + 
                            streamSize);
                      publishProgress((int) ((totalBytesTransferred/file.length())*100));
                   }
           }
      );
```

This I suspect is where its failing! If you're not getting any logcat with the string "*CopyStreamAdapter*", it means your handler in this is not getting fired!

Comment: I did not get anything what should I do?

Comment: reading this - http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/net/io/Util.html#copyStream(java.io.InputStream, java.io.OutputStream, int, long, org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamListener) - notice CopyStreamListener - you're using CopyStreamAdapter....

Comment: @tOmm13b so do you mean should I change it?

Comment: alright, best thing for you to do is to **try** it out and see how you fare and you will learn so much from this - debugging, testing and watching the logcat!

Comment: lets see! I hope I will find out the solution.

Comment: @tOmm13b still not found any solution :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15159/discussion-between-answer88-and-t0mm13b)