# issue using progressbar to track ftp fiel upload

Tags: c#, winforms, ftp

So i am trying to use a progressbar to visually show the progress of a file upload via ftp.
I cant seem to figure out as to why, the progressbar and 3 other labels (labelSpeed, labelPerc, labelUploaded) isn't working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

PS: I attached a snipet of my code for viewing.

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch(); //<-- The stopwatch which we will be using to calculate the upload speed

public void Upload(string ftpServer, string username, string password, string filename, string folder1, string folder2, string folder3)//<-- Uploads image to ftp directory
    {
        string ftpfolderpath = folder1 + "/" + folder2 + "/" + folder3;
        MakeFTPDir(ftpServer, ftpfolderpath, username, password); //<-- Makes the new directory, if there isnt one already

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(Completed); //<--NEW
            client.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged); //<--NEW
            sw.Start(); //<-- Start the stopwatch which we will be using to calculate the upload speed

            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            client.UploadFile(ftpServer + "/" + folder1 + "/" + folder2 + "/" + folder3 + "/" + new FileInfo(filename).Name, "STOR", filename); //<-- uploads image to ftp Directory
        }
    }

    private void ProgressChanged(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e) //<-- The event that will fire whenever the progress of the WebClient is changed
    {
        // Calculate upload speed and output it to labelSpeed.
        labelSpeed.Text = string.Format("{0} kb/s", (e.BytesSent / 1024d / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.00"));

        // Update the progressbar percentage only when the value is not the same.
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

        // Show the percentage on our label.
        labelPerc.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";

        // Update the label with how much data have been uploaded so far and the total size of the file we are currently uploading
        labelUploaded.Text = string.Format("{0} MB's / {1} MB's",
            (e.BytesSent / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00"),
            (e.TotalBytesToSend / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00"));
    }

    private void Completed(object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e) //<-- The event that will trigger when the WebClient is completed
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            string error = e.Error.ToString(); // error = "Custom error message here";
            MessageBox.Show(error);
            return;
        }

        sw.Reset(); // Reset the stopwatch.

        if (e.Cancelled == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Image Upload has been canceled.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Image Upload completed!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FTP progress bar uploading file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883636/ftp-progress-bar-uploading-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [UploadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esst63h0(v=vs.110).aspx) method which is blocking the calling UI thread. Instead, on the GUI thread, one should use [UploadFileAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144233(v=vs.110).aspx) to not block.

One can see an example of something similar [WebClient.UploadProgressChanged Event (System.Net)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadprogresschanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

**EDIT:**: Here is what I meant. Replace

```
client.UploadFile(ftpServer + "/" + folder1 + "/" + folder2 + "/" + folder3 + "/" + new FileInfo(filename).Name, "STOR", filename); //<-- uploads image to ftp Directory
```

with

```
client.UploadFileAsync(new Uri(ftpServer + "/" + folder1 + "/" + folder2 + "/" + folder3 + "/" + new FileInfo(filename).Name), "STOR", filename); //<-- uploads image to ftp Directory
```

Comment: What i don't understand is that, using the 'UploadFileAsync' method, i do not see where the upload location(where to save the image) is specified from the example link you provided.

So i made the changes suggested:
    Uri uri = new Uri(picboxEmployeePic.ImageLocation);
                client.UploadFileAsync(uri, "POST", filename); 

Now i get a  error.
Below are pictures for reference:
[link](http://i693.photobucket.com/albums/vv293/saturobi360/Error/uploadProgress_CHANGE_zps6uqowlkv.jpg)
[link](http://i693.photobucket.com/albums/vv293/saturobi360/Error/uploadProgress_ERROR2_zpssigdeo9t.jpg)

Comment: @saturobi360 I think you misunderstood me. All I meant is to add `Async` at the end of `UploadFile` (like `client.UploadFileAsync(ftpServer + "/" + folder1 + "/" ...`)

Comment: When i added 'Async' to the end of 'Uploadfile', I got a System.ArgumentNullException and a System.Net.WebException.

The error also states that the overloaded method match for 'System.Net.WebClient.UploadFileAsync(System.Uri, string, string) has some invalid arguments. 
Below is screenshot[Link](http://i693.photobucket.com/albums/vv293/saturobi360/Error/uploadProgress_ERROR3_zpsc7wcoin1.jpg)

Comment: Thanks alot. The labels now work.
Now just wondering why the progressbar isnt working.

Is there a set of properties i need to assign to the Progressbar, in order for it to work?